# Flex div is growing beyond parent div based on child height

Tags: html, css

I have created following html element.

Here `remaining-height` class is supposed to be remaining height of `container-div` which is 100 - 15 = 85px, but because `grand-child-div` is 200 px, `remaining-height` div is going beyond `container-div`.

How can I prevent `remaining-height` div to be remaining height of `container-div` which is 100 - 15 = 85px.

Based on comment I am adding one detail. `remaining-height` will have scroll inside that div as `grand-child-div` will have more height than `remaining-height`.

```html
<div class="container-div" style="height:100px">
  <div class="fixed-height">
  </div>
  <div class="remaining-height">
    <div>
      <div class="grand-child-div" style="height:200px">  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is css

```css
.remaining-height {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.fixed-height {
  height: 15px;
  background-color: green;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6cg8kmqh/

Comment: If a child has a declared height, there's nothing appropriate you can do it stop changing the parent height because that's just how height works - it's containing the child and that child is 200px tall. Other than controlling the overflow, you'll have to avoid specific height values.

Comment: Can't parent height have scroll? That's what was expectation.

Comment: That's controlling the overflow. You can add `overflow: auto` to `.remaining-height`. That being said, you've not implemented flex properly so it won't work alone without other changes: https://jsfiddle.net/4bLfvcxu

Comment: Seems to be working. Still, in my application, there is still more layer causing the issue. But that is a separate question to ask. Please add your comment as an answer. I will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As worked out in the comments, what you want to do is control the overflow. You can add `overflow: auto` to `.remaining-height` to allow it to scroll (once flex is setup correctly). See [jsfiddle.net/4bLfvcxu](https://jsfiddle.net/4bLfvcxu).

Answer (score -1):

Try to add to the element with the class: remaining-height, `height: calc(100% - 15px);`

Comment: Then there is no meaning of using flex if I had to do that. Because someone can change 15% to something else then in remaining class also I will have to change every time.